# Reading metadata from images in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, image, metadata

I'm aware that WPF allows you to use images that require WIC codecs to view (for the sake of argument, say a digital camera RAW file); however I can only see that it lets you show the image natively, but I can't see anyway of getting at the meta-data (for example, the exposure time).

It obviously can be done, as Windows Explorer shows it, but is this exposed through the .net API or do you reckon that it is just down to calling the native COM interfaces

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out my [Intuipic](http://intuipic.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/7348#114514) project. In particular, the [BitmapOrientationConverter](http://intuipic.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/7348#114514) class, which reads metadata to determine the image's orientation:

```
private const string _orientationQuery = "System.Photo.Orientation";
...

using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    BitmapFrame bitmapFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(fileStream, BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation, BitmapCacheOption.None);
    BitmapMetadata bitmapMetadata = bitmapFrame.Metadata as BitmapMetadata;

    if ((bitmapMetadata != null) && (bitmapMetadata.ContainsQuery(_orientationQuery)))
    {
        object o = bitmapMetadata.GetQuery(_orientationQuery);

        if (o != null)
        {
            //refer to http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html for details on orientation values
            switch ((ushort) o)
            {
                case 6:
                    return 90D;
                case 3:
                    return 180D;
                case 8:
                    return 270D;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It's weird that BitmapMetadata doesn't contain an `Orientation` property like it has for DateTaken, Author etc.

Comment: For other people coming here via google, the `_orientationQuery` in Kent's example above is `"System.Photo.Orientation"`

Comment: Kent, any reason why you're only handling three values? According to this article, you should be handling the mirrored values as well (2, 4, 5, and 7).

http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2012/07/28/exif-orientation-handling-is-a-ghetto/

Comment: @Charlie: just ignorance - I wasn't aware of the mirroring values. That said, I'm not entirely sure I understand when or why taking a photo "inside out" would ever occur and thus how the mirroring values are useful.

Comment: After testing this on my own library of photos, just handling those 3 values seems to be enough to catch all of the improperly rotated ones. I guess I don't have any "mirrored" images. :/

Comment: Well, you can't just return an angle for these cases anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Whilst WPF does provide these APIs, they're not very friendly and they're not particularly fast. I suspect they're doing a lot of interop.

I maintain a [simple open-source library](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet) for extracting metadata from images and videos. It's 100% C# with no P/Invoke.

```
// Read all metadata from the image
var directories = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(stream);

// Find the so-called Exif "SubIFD" (which may be null)
var subIfdDirectory = directories.OfType<ExifSubIfdDirectory>().FirstOrDefault();

// Read the orientation
var orientation = subIfdDirectory?.GetInt(ExifDirectoryBase.TagOrientation);

switch (orientation)
{
    case 6:
        return 90D;
    case 3:
        return 180D;
    case 8:
        return 270D;
}
```

In my benchmarks, this is 17 times faster than the WPF API. If you only want Exif from JPEG, use the following and it's over 30 times faster:

```
var directories = JpegMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(stream, new[] { new ExifReader() });
```

The *metadata-extractor* library is available via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MetadataExtractor/) and the [code's on GitHub](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet).

Credit is due to the many contributors who've helped the project since it started in 2002.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `ExifDirectoryBase.TagOrientation`?